# How to set y coordinate using location.absolute when plotting a shape?

Tags: pine-script

I'd like to stack two `triangledown` shapes vertically, so one sits atop the other.

I see there is a `location.absolute` location, but I can't find any instructions or examples regarding how to actually set the y coordinate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plotshape, y coordinate is always the series. Syntax as follows:

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_plotshape

Try this code:

```
study("My Script", overlay = true)
atr = atr(22)
plotshape(close + 2*atr, style= shape.triangleup, location=location.absolute, size = size.tiny, color = color.green)
```